# UI not updating using MVVM toolkit in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I am trying to change the size of a grid using data binding in order to be able to expand certain sections of my UI. I have looked online and nothing really seems to work. My window has a frame that loads a "root page" with another frame inside of it as seen in rootpage.xaml below. I have added a textbox but that does not seem to work. Interestingly enough, when I click the button present on the page. I do get a line outputted so my code is running. Adding a breakpoint shows similar results that the property FullScreenValue does in fact change. I think I am missing something in order to get the PropertyChanged event to be received or I may be unintentionally instancing multiple instances of my ViewModel. Looking for a solution.

My root page loaded into the frame in my window:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MVVM.Views.rootPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MVVM.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ViewModels="using:MVVM.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:RootPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    
    
    <Grid x:Name="frameGrid"  ColumnDefinitions="*, *" RowDefinitions ="*, *" Grid.Row="1" Margin="15, 0, 15, 0" >
        <Frame x:Name="topleftFrame" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="8" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding FullScreenValue,Mode=OneWay}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding FullScreenValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="FullScreen"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,5,5,10" Command="{Binding FullScreenCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        Visibility="Visible"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullScreenValue, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
        
</Page>
```

My ViewModel:

```cs
namespace MVVM.ViewModels
{
    public partial class RootPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int fullScreenValue;

        public RootPageViewModel()
        {
            fullScreenValue = 1;
        }
        
        [ICommand]
        void FullScreen()
        {
            fullScreenValue = 2;
            Debug.WriteLine("HI");
            
        }



    }

}
```

As you can see I am trying to make use of the community toolkit. I have tried replacing some of these generated snippets with standard mvvm properties and commands to no avail. If I change the constructor to have a value of 2 I get my desired result, but can't seem to do it with this button! Send help.

My desired result is upon clicking the button, the frame will now span 2 columns and 2 rows instead of 1 column and 1 row. Maybe because this sort of UI concerns strictly the view it does not necessarily need a ViewModel but nonetheless I am still looking for help as I feel like I will run into this problem in the future. I am new to a lot of things in the Microsoft ecosystem so please forgive me if this is a repeat question and I just could not understand other answers.

Comment: Change `fullScreenValue = 2;` by `FullScreenValue = 2;`  You must update the public Property to trigger OnNotifyPropertyChange.

Comment: @McNets Wow! This ended up working perfectly thank you so much. I have a question though. When I set a breakpoint in my code, I thought that updating the private variable will automatically update the public property. So in this case do I even need a private variable? In practice should my private variable be something already existing in my model and I just need a public property to expose this and notify the View? Meaning in my code somewhere I have to declare that `public property = private variable`? I am studying MVVM recently and I clearly have a long way to go. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A property have a Setter and a Getter, is there where you set or get the value of the private member. BTW you can use Properties without private members. You should read about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties

Comment: @McNets Thank you so much for the resource! So if I have a private member which is subject to change (maybe upon completion of a task or something else). When this private member changes, is there a way to automatically update it to the property? I have a getter that returns my private variable but that does not seem to notify property changed even though breakpoints show that the public property is getting the private member. Or am I fundamentally missing something about properties or perhaps just need to type `property = private member` to be called upon the completion of the task?